# Change asset pipeline directory names in grails? or have grails use existing structure?

Tags: grails

Is it possible to customize the asset pipeline plugin such that instead of the default directories that I have to refactor my existing objects in to this format:

> grails-app/assets/javascript
>   grails-app/assets/images
>   grails-app/assets/stylesheets

I can rename directories like such "javascript" to "js" and "stylesheets" to "css"? The reason being I already have my resources organized outside of grails in:

```
assets/staticimages
assets/js
assets/css
assets/animatedgifs
```

Comment: If your question is "Can I rename directories ....?", then yes you can have any directory under `grails-app/assets` as `grails-app/assets/foo/bar.js`

Answer (score 0):

The `assets-pipeline` plugin doesn't impose any directory structure on where you keep your assets except for the fact that they have to be *somewhere* under `grails-app/assets`. For example, you can put them in:

- grails-app/assets/js
- grails-app/assets/css
- grails-app/assets/img

or

- grails-app/assets/javascript
- grails-app/assets/style
- grails-app/assets/images

you can even put everything directly in `grails-app/assets` (though I wouldn't recommend this).